# Javascript updates HTML classes before it is expected to

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, createelement

**The problem**

I am making Pacman, and I wrote the following function to **initialize the board**. How is it possible that the board is rendered, even though I only add the styling classes to the square elements in my 'squares' array? As far as I can see I never updated the classes of the div elements inside my 'grid' (which holds the actual div html elements that are shown to the user).

**The function**

```
function createBoard() {
    for (let i = 0; i < layout.length; i++) {
        const square = document.createElement('div')
        grid.appendChild(square)
        squares.push(square)
        
        
        if (layout[i] === 0) {
            squares[i].classList.add('pac-dot')
        } else if (layout[i] === 1) {
            squares[i].classList.add('wall')
        } else if (layout[i] === 3) {
            squares[i].classList.add('power-pellet')
        }
    }
}
```

The function **iterates through an array (layout)** that holds information of how the board should look. For each element of that array **a div (square) is created** which is then **added to the 'grid'** (a div element in my html file that holds all newly created divs). The square div is then added to the 'squares' array, which also holds all the square divs, but is not present in my html file.

The second part of the function **adds a class to the square** in the squares array , based on how the board should look. The result is the following board:

[image: The Pacman Board]

Comment: `grid.appendChild(square)` if grid is already in the DOM, the DOM will be updated with everything you do to square

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, grid is already in the DOM. To check if I understand it correctly: so if an element in the DOM is depended on a javascript variable, and I change the value of the javascript variable, the DOM element will be updated automatically?

Comment: Yes. If you add an element to the dom and save it in a var,, all manipulations of the var will be reflected in the dom.If you change the CONTENT of the var, it will no longer apply of course

Comment: @mplungjan Can you explain what you mean with changing the content of the var? Do you mean updating the value of the var to something that is not an html element?

Comment: `const square = document.createElement('div'); grid.appendChild(square); squares.push(square); squares[0].style.color="red";  squares[0] = "Hello"` - now you cannot update the first square using the first entry in the array anymore

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `grid` is a DOM element, then `grid.appendChild(square)` will add the square to the DOM. After that, any change you apply to the element's style will be visible.

So for example, let's say you have the following HTML:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Now let's add a child `div` to it:

```
const grid = document.getElementById("grid");
const square = document.createElement("div");
grid.appendChild(square);
```

This actually *changes* the HTML, to be as if it was written like this:

```
<div id="grid">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Adding a class to the div will also change the markup. So after this:

```
square.classList.add('wall');
```

The HTML will look like so:

```
<div id="grid">
    <div class="wall"></div>
</div>
```